# How many seasons are there in Chroma Squad?

Tags: chroma-squad

I just started Season 4 of [Chroma Squad](http://www.chromasquad.com/). How many seasons are there in total?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the [Episode Editor](https://store.steampowered.com/app/810600/Chroma_Squad__Episode_Editor/), there are (at least) 6 seasons.